# C++ Convert a subnet prefix to decimal representation

Tags: c++, prefix, data-conversion, subnet

I have a subnet prefix as a DWORD value (it's a /24 subnet so the DWORD value is 24). I would like to convert this to the decimal representation (which would be 4294967040). What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this will achieve what I need. If you have a better solution, please post it! :)

```
DWORD prefix = 24;
unsigned long mask = (0xFFFFFFFF << (32 - prefix)) & 0xFFFFFFFF;
```